# Ethereum Wallet 0.3.9 (Mist) "could not unlock signer account" a few times today when sending a transaction

Tags: wallets

Ethereum Wallet 0.3.9
MacOS X 10.11.3

Now it works again, but for an hour I was unable to send a transaction and getting the message "could not unlock signer account".

Maybe a bug? 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the latest version 0.4.0.
This could happen if the connection with the under the hood node is lost, though i have no idea why this would happen.